# How can sizeof determine the exact size of a structure im memory if no object of this structure has been created?

Tags: c, memory, data-structures, struct, sizeof

I came across an issue by determining the size of a structure. I´ve found out that it is possible to determine the size of a structure with the preceded keyword `struct` inside of the sizeof-operation, although no object has been created for the respective structure:

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   struct struct1
   {
        char a[20];
        int v,i;
        double grw;
   };

   printf("Size of struct1 in Byte: %lu",sizeof(struct struct1));

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Size of struct1 in Byte: 40
```

---

How is that possible?

How can sizeof determine the size of a structure with the help of the `struct` keyword inside of the sizeof-operation, if no object of this structure has been created?

Or has been an `struct1` object created, I did not know about?

I´ve thought a structure is only a datatype, but not an object of its own type.

Comment: How would the compiler allocate an object of type `struct struct1` if it didn't know it's size? (The `struct` keyword is not relevant. `sizeof(int)` is perfectly fine too.)

Comment: This sizeof is just telling you how much memory is needed to create an "object" of type struct1

Comment: `sizeof` infers the size of the `struct` from its structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than variable length arrays, `sizeof` does not *need* an instance of the type to figure out its size, it can work it out just based on the type definition itself.

In the case you give (shown below), it actually knows, just from that type definition, how big the object will be (the size of each individual field plus whatever padding is needed for alignment between each field and after the final field) - the comments give one possibility:

```
struct struct1 {
    char a[20];  // 20 bytes @ 0.
    int v,i;     // Two 4-byte values @ 20 (a multiple of 4, so already aligned).
                 // 4 bytes padding to align next 8-byte double.
    double grw;  // 8 bytes @ 32 (a multiple of 8, aligned due to padding above).
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` needs to be able to determine the size of different types otherwise it wouldn't know how much space to allocate when you do need to.

The `struct` definition indicates how much space is going to be used.

One allocation might be like this:

- `char a[20]`: 20 bytes.
- `int c, i`: 16bit each, so 4 bytes.
- `double grw`: 128bit, so 16 bytes.

**Total: 40 bytes**

Comment: This is incorrect. For most compilers, `int` is 32 bits and _not_ 16. Early 8086 used 16 [and some mc68000], but, these days, 32 is more general. But, more importantly, `double` is 64 bits [8 bytes] and _not_ 128 bits [16 bytes]

Comment: Careful, @Craig, you shouldn't confuse "common" with "mandated". The standard specifies *minimum* requirements for each type (int, double, etc) but it does not specify *maximum* requirements. I'm not even sure it requires IEEE754 formats at all for floating point, instead opting for certain *properties* of the underlying type (like a sign bit, ranges and precision and so on). So, since blueteeth stated that "one allocation *might* be like this", I believe the answer is actually correct.